# how to replace text in a particular column on a table in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have an table Employee, with a Description column. In the description column I have the text
`<br />`. Now I need to replace this text with the text `<br>`.

Is there any way that i could modify the value in the column itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Update Employee
Set Description = Replace(Description , '<br />','<br>')
Where IDColumn = RecordIdValue
```

You can omit the `where` clause if you want to update ALL rows in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function with a [`UPDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) statement:

```
UPDATE EMployee
SET Description = REPLACE(Description, 'find this text', 'replacement')
```